# Is there a way to synchronise Orchard CMS tenants across a web farm?

Tags: orchardcms

I've deployed a multi tenant Orchard application in Azure and have noticed that when adding a tenant via the host site it is only available immediately on the same web instance as the host. If I have a few web role instances then my request fails when I am routed to a different instance. Is there a mechanism for synchronising the loaded tenants on each web role instance? If not, I will make us of a Service Bus topic and publish a tenant refresh on each instance (I note the "_tenantsToRestart" collection in the DefaultOrchardHost).

Second question, does the warmup module work with blob storage? It seems to be doing something in app data but I'm not sure whether this is backed by blob storage.

Thanks
Matt